# English horror film where mice kill people with scissor like weapons

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I watched this movie a while ago, and this is what I remember from it:

### Necessary Details:

- The movie was in English
- Based on horror
- The horror side of things were mice that killed people with weapons such as scissors
- Victims were a family including (I think) a father, a mother and 2-3 children.
- It was in colour
- I am sure it was filmed in the USA.
- I don't know when it was showing.

### What I remember from the plot (not in any particular order):

- There was a basement which had mice in it that used everyday items as weapons (scissors, knife etc.)
- There was a visitor (another man) who went down into the basement to get something and was attacked by the mice.
- The mice crawled all over him, some went on his head and some went to his shoulders and arms etc.
- One that was on his head stabbed him in the eye with a knife, the man screamed.
- One that was on his shoulder stabbed him in the shoulder (in the soft part(deltoid muscle) with a pair of scissors and went deep.
- Other mice stabbed him wherever they could find a soft spot.
- The man then swatted the mice away, they left him to die.
- He staggered up the stairs to the house, but when he got there, there was the mother, who gasped when she saw him.
- The man then pulled the scissors out of his shoulder (the knife still protruding out of his eye) which resulted in blood squirting out of his shoulder.
- He then fell to the floor and died.
- The family was in shock from this death.
- There was a part where the family were fighting back against the mice in the basement
- The wife was stabbed numerous times, from what I remember, she was dragged by the mice into this rock hole cave drop thing hidden in the basement (presumed to be where the mice came from)
- When the husband ran to help her get away, she fell through backwards witha  determined look on her face.
- The husband looked into the hole and yelled her name
- The camera focuses on a dull, dark, rocky looking cave drop.

**The characters were of Caucasian ethnicity (all of them were)**

***Please help guys, your help here is much appreciated. Thanks again.***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [Don't Be Afraid of the Dark](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270761/combined) from 2010 that stars Katie Holmes and Guy Pearce and was co-written by Guillermo del Toro.

> A young girl is sent to live with her estranged father and his girlfriend at their new home. The father, Alex has plans to spruce up the home with the help of his interior decorator girlfriend, Kim. The previous owner of the home was a famous painter who mysteriously disappeared. Alex's daughter, Sally, soon discovers the cause of the painter's disappearance.

The creatures in the film aren't exactly mice but rather rodent-like demons, and one of the workmen in the house is attacked exactly as you described. [A remake of a 1973 TV movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Be_Afraid_of_the_Dark_(1973_film)). Here's the trailer: